# How do i download a large collection in Firestore with Python without getting at 503 error?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to count the number of docs in a firestore collection with python.  When i use `db.collection('xxxx").stream()` i get the following error:

```
 503 The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.
```

about half way through.  It was working fine. Here is the code:

```
    docs = db.collection(u'theDatabase').stream()
    count = 0
    for doc in docs:
        count += 1
    print (count)
```

Every time I get a 503 error at about 73,000 records.  Does anyone know how to overcome the 20 second timeout?

Comment: If you think this is a bug, contact Firebase support directly. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a recursive function to batch document retrievals and keep them under the timeout. Here's an example based on the [delete_collections snippet](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data#collections):

```
from google.cloud import firestore

# Project ID is determined by the GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable
db = firestore.Client()


def count_collection(coll_ref, count, cursor=None):

    if cursor is not None:
        docs = [snapshot.reference for snapshot
                in coll_ref.limit(1000).order_by("__name__").start_after(cursor).stream()]
    else:
        docs = [snapshot.reference for snapshot
                in coll_ref.limit(1000).order_by("__name__").stream()]

    count = count + len(docs)

    if len(docs) == 1000:
        return count_collection(coll_ref, count, docs[999].get())
    else:
        print(count)


count_collection(db.collection('users'), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Juan!  that did it.

Answer (score 19):

Although Juan's answer works for basic counting, in case you need more of the data from Firebase and not just the `id` (a common use case of which is total migration of the data that is not through GCP), the recursive algorithm will eat your memory.

So I took Juan's code and transformed it to a standard iterative algorithm. Hope this helps someone.

```py
limit = 1000  # Reduce this if it uses too much of your RAM
def stream_collection_loop(collection, count, cursor=None):
    while True:
        docs = []  # Very important. This frees the memory incurred in the recursion algorithm.

        if cursor:
            docs = [snapshot for snapshot in
                    collection.limit(limit).order_by('__name__').start_after(cursor).stream()]
        else:
            docs = [snapshot for snapshot in collection.limit(limit).order_by('__name__').stream()]

        for doc in docs:
            print(doc.id)
            print(count)
            # The `doc` here is already a `DocumentSnapshot` so you can already call `to_dict` on it to get the whole document.
            process_data_and_log_errors_if_any(doc)
            count = count + 1

        if len(docs) == limit:
            cursor = docs[limit-1]
            continue

        break


stream_collection_loop(db_v3.collection('collection'), 0)
```

Comment: it works. You know which is the method to raise stream() limit error?

Comment: I don't remember the exact exception. Maybe try to force it to appear first, note the name, and have autocomplete write it out for you.

Comment: Works well and more helpful than Firestore documentation. Thank you!

Comment: I spent more time to develop a **"ready to use" function** for sharing with anyone in the same situation. You can just copy and paste from **[my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66218444/how-to-use-python-to-read-a-large-firestore-collection-without-running-into-503/66218445#66218445)**

Answer (score 1):

In other answers was shown how to use the pagination to solve the timeout issue.

I suggest to use a generator in combination with pagination, which lets you to process the documents in the same way as you were doing it with query.stream().

Here is an example of function that takes a Query and returns a generator in the same way as the Query stream() method.

```py
from typing import Generator, Optional, Any

from google.cloud.firestore import Query, DocumentSnapshot


def paginate_query_stream(
    query: Query, 
    order_by: str,
    cursor: Optional[DocumentSnapshot] = None,
    page_size: int = 10000,
) -> Generator[DocumentSnapshot, Any, None]:
    paged_query = query.order_by(order_by)
    document = cursor
    has_any = True
    while has_any:
        has_any = False
        if document:
            paged_query = paged_query.start_after(document)
        paged_query = paged_query.limit(page_size)
        for document in paged_query.stream():
            has_any = True
            yield document
```

Take in mind if your target collection constantly grows then you need to filter the upper bound in the query in advance to prevent a potential infinite loop.

A usage example with counting of documents.

```py
from google.cloud.firestore import Query

docs = db.collection(u'theDatabase')
# Query without conditions, get all documents.
query = Query(docs)

count = 0
for doc in paginate_query_stream(query, order_by='__name__'):
    count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (my collection has 100 small objects):

```
import copy

col_ref = db.collection("my_collection")
docs = col_ref.stream()

permanent_docs = [copy.deepcopy(doc.to_dict()) for doc in docs]
```