# How to convert nested object into dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, object, google-cloud-firestore

I want to backup my firestore data into mysql using Python 3.
right now I am struggling to convert the object into a dictionary.

my data structure :

status > phone_number > time_stamp > message_status

```py
docs = db.collection(u'status').stream()
for doc in docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

when I print the `docs` it shows `<generator object Query.stream at 0x113c306d8>`. I have tried the above command but I don't get the resul.

Comment: Try `doc.__dict__`

Comment: if you want to print the list you could do  list(docs)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh not working :(

Comment: @H.Rabiee it shows empty list. hmm weird.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary comprehension to turn the `docs` generator into a dict:

```
docs = db.collection(u'status').stream()

docs_dict = {doc.id:doc.to_dict() for doc in docs}

# print dictionary keys
for k in docs_dict:
    print(u'doc id: {}'.format(k))
```

Also, watch out for the timeout on the `stream()` method. If you have thousands of docs in your collection, you will need to make multiple `stream()` requests or [use a recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011623/how-do-i-download-a-large-collection-in-firestore-with-python-without-getting-at/56012426#56012426).