# google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable when using stream

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to iterate over all my documents in Firestore. I run the following in Python

```
from google.cloud.firestore import Client

client = Client()

docs = list()
for es in client.collection('exchange-statements').stream():
    docs.append(es)
```

but it yields the following error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.
```

I am using `google-cloud-firestore v1.2.0`.

### EDIT

Since my problem is about streaming documents and not just counting then it differs from the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012426/2834295).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i download a large collection in Firestore with Python without getting at 503 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011623/how-do-i-download-a-large-collection-in-firestore-with-python-without-getting-at)

Comment: Ah yes you are right. My mistake and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012426/2834295) I came up with a generic solution. However I wonder if there isn't a better solution out of the box.

```
def iterate(collection_name, batch_size=5000, cursor=None):
    query = client.collection(collection_name).limit(batch_size).order_by('__name__')
    if cursor:
        query = query.start_after(cursor)

    for doc in query.stream():
        yield doc
    
    if 'doc' in locals():
        yield from iterate(collection_name, batch_size, doc)
```

Comment: The `else` can and should be removed FYI

Comment: No then you only get the first batch!?

Comment: That's not true, if you try it out you will see that it works. Even without trying it, you can tell right away that the `else` does nothing since there is a `for` loop in the same level as the `if` that comes before. As a result, the `else` is ignored because there is no preceding `if` that it is associated with.

Comment: No. The first .stream() only yields the first batch. When there are no docs left in the batch then you continue to yield from the next batch.

Comment: I'm not arguing that your code doesn't work. I'm saying that your `else` statement is dead code because it doesn't get associated with a preceding `if` statement. If you run both versions of the function you will get the same result. I'm recommending that the `else` be removed because it's misleading to someone trying to understand what is happening in the function.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but you are wrong. If the else statement wasn’t there then you’d only get the first batch. Note that the last statement yields from the next batch by setting the cursor to the last doc which was yielded

Comment: The else statement is simply linked to the for loop. So the else statement executes when the for loop is done. I could omit the else line of course (the single line) but not the statement inside else. Is that simply what you suggest? More on for-else here; https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. I’m not sure - to me it sounded like you wanted to omit the else statement completely

Comment: Ah I was unaware of `for/else` statements; however, there is no `break` statement in your `for` loop so the `else` still doesn't do anything and can be removed.