# Python Google cloud firestore error 504 Deadline Exceeded

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function fore firestore in python where I do a for loop for all the users of one collection, then I go into another collection to take some metrics and I update this metrics in the first collections.

I run the function but in some point in the execution the function breaks giving me this error:

```
_Rendezvous                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py in next(self)
     78         try:
---> 79             return six.next(self._wrapped)
     80         except grpc.RpcError as exc:

~\Anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py in __next__(self)
    363     def __next__(self):
--> 364         return self._next()
    365 

~\Anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py in _next(self)
    346             else:
--> 347                 raise self
    348             while True:

_Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
    details = "Deadline Exceeded"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1570660422.708000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:216.58.202.234:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1052,"grpc_message":"Deadline Exceeded","grpc_status":4}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DeadlineExceeded                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-05c9cefdafb4> in <module>
----> 1 update_collection__persons()

<ipython-input-19-6e2bdd597a6e> in update_collection__persons()
     10     counter_secs = 0
     11 
---> 12     for person_doc in person_docs:
     13         person_dict = person_doc.to_dict()
     14         last_updated = person_dict['last_updated']

~\Anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\firestore_v1\query.py in stream(self, transaction)
    766         )
    767 
--> 768         for response in response_iterator:
    769             if self._all_descendants:
    770                 snapshot = _collection_group_query_response_to_snapshot(

~\Anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py in next(self)
     79             return six.next(self._wrapped)
     80         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 81             six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
     82 
     83     # Alias needed for Python 2/3 support.

~\Anaconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

I have been looking up for a solution, there is not much information, here I found a similar problem: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8933

So I tried to use this code but is not working. This is my function:

```
def update_collection__persons():   
    persons = db.collection(u'collections__persons')
    person_docs = persons.stream()


    counter_secs = 0

    for person_doc in person_docs:
        person_dict = person_doc.to_dict()
        last_updated = person_dict['last_updated']
        last_processed = person_dict['last_processed']
        dt_last_updated = datetime(1, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=last_updated/10)
        dt_last_processed = datetime(1, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=last_processed/10)

        if dt_last_processed < dt_last_updated:
            orders = db.collection(u'collection__orders').where(u'email', u'==', person_dict['email'])
            orders_docs = orders.stream()

            sum_price = 0
            count = 0
            date_add_list = []

            for order_doc in orders_docs:
                order_dict = order_doc.to_dict() 
                sum_price += order_dict['total_price']
                count +=1
                date_add_list.append(order_dict['dateAdded'])
            if count > 0:
                data = {'metrics': {'LTV': sum_price,
                                    'AOV': sum_price/count,
                                    'Quantity_orders': count,
                                    'first_order_date': min(date_add_list),
                                    'last_order_date': max(date_add_list)},
                         'last_processed': int((datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1, 1, 1)).total_seconds() * 10000000)}

                 db.collection(u'collection__persons').document(person_dict['email']).set(data, merge = True)
```

I have created a counter_secs just to see if the function is breaking always in the same query but it is not.

Also after run the function if I see random users for some of them I have update their data, so it is working but breaking in some point

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a 60 second timeout for `persons.stream()`. Instead of processing each document as you stream, try fetching all the documents upfront:

```
person_docs = [snapshot for snapshot in persons.stream()]
```

If you have more documents than you can fetch in 60 seconds, try a recursive function [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011623/how-do-i-download-a-large-collection-in-firestore-with-python-without-getting-at/56012426#56012426).

Same for the orders:

```
orders_docs = [snapshot for snapshot in orders.stream()]
```

Comment: Can you explain me for what is this start_after(cursor)?

He inizialite the cursor as none, so when it is going to have a different value than None? what is the different between start_after and no use this start_after?

Comment: Sure, it's a [query cursor](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor). That function splits up a large query into batches of 1000 documents at a time. After fetching a batch of 1000 documents, the function passes the 1000th document as a query cursor to get the next 1000 documents, `count_collection(coll_ref, count, docs[999].get())`.

Comment: Isn't this way just lost the purpose of using `.stream()` instead of `.get()`? which consume lots of memory

Answer (score 1):

I was dev'ing on a WSL-Ubuntu set up with Firebase local emulators, hibernated overnight, came back in the morning and got this err on a 'doc_ref.set...'.  Shutdown and restarted WSL, everything ran smooth...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact issue when I was fetching all documents to convert it into a JSON.

I did it as follow.

```py
 def load_documents(self, path):
    collection = self.db
    nodes = path.split("/")

    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            collection = collection.collection(node) 
        else:
            collection = collection.document(node)
    stream = collection.stream()

    for doc in stream:
        print("* Fetching document: {}".format(doc.get("filename")))
        self.memes.append(self._fetch_doc(doc))
```

```py
def _fetch_doc(self, doc):
    try:
        return {
            "caption": doc.get("caption"),
            "filename": doc.get("filename"),
            "url": doc.get("url")
        }
    except:
        self._fetch_doc(doc)
```

I fetched recursively if I got an exception.

Comment: The actual exception is `DeadlineExceeded` and it happens during the `for doc in stream` line not the `doc.get(...)` so this will still crash.

Comment: I answered this question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61663938/3778645. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

I was still facing the issue after following @juan-lara's solution, converting the documents into dict finally worked for me.

```
person_docs = [snapshot.to_dict() for snapshot in persons.stream()]
```