# How to Query for documents in a sub collection in Firestore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I know there is some limitation on how to query documents in a subcollection from the root collection, but when you have a reference to the sub collection it shouldnt be a problem, should it (???)

The structure looks like this:

SensorName (Collection) -> MyDocument (Document) -> SensorHistory (SubCollection)

```
doc_ref = db.collection('sensorData').document('Engineroom').collection('History').order_by("timestamp").where(u"SensorType", u"==", 'temp')
result = doc_ref.stream().to_dict()
print(result)
```

This is the error i am getting

> result = doc_ref.stream().to_dict() AttributeError: 'generator' object
>   has no attribute 'to_dict'

Do I really need to put my History collection in the root to able to query it ?

Or is it me that have made a mistake in my code ? :)

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: No, it's just saying `to_dict` isn't on the result of `get`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i am not sure if i understand what you mean :)

Comment: Where are you getting to_dict from? It doesn't exist on the result of the collection retrieval.

Comment: The error message says it all, really. `.stream()` returns a generator, which doesn't have `.to_dict()` method. _Do I really need to put my History collection in the root to able to query it ?_ I'm not sure how that's related. What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The `stream()` method returns a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator) of document snapshots. You need to get the doc snapshots out of the generator before you call `to_dict`:

```
result = doc_ref.stream()

for doc in result:
    print(doc.to_dict())
```

Comment: If `result`matches to a lot of documents, you may run into a 60 second time out. If you do, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313177/python-google-cloud-firestore-error-504-deadline-exceeded/58313643#58313643).