# Faced Mutation error in bigtable while writing lakhs of records

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable

I am facing mutation error in bigtable when writing hundreds of thousands of rows using python bigtable. I am using table.mutate_rows(rows). Below is the error:

> raise TooManyMutationsError(google.cloud.bigtable.table.TooManyMutationsError: Maximum number of mutations is 100000

So for this error, i found some solution using mutation_batcher. After that i applied the logic for mutation_batcher and used it like below.

```
batcher = table.mutations_batcher(flush_count=50000, max_row_bytes=5242880)
    batcher.mutate_rows(rows)
    batcher.flush()
```

After waiting for write for 5-10 minutes then below are the errors which I face today.

> grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of
> RPC that terminated with:
> status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
> details = "Deadline Exceeded"
> debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1600250654.698000000","description":"Error received from
> peer
> ,"file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Deadline
> exceeded","grpc_status":4}"
>
> grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of
> RPC that terminated with:status = statusCode.UNKNOWN   details =
> "Stream removed"  debug_error_string =
> ""created":"@1600251572.659000000","description":"Error received from
> peer
> file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Stream
> removed","grpc_status":2}"

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313177/python-google-cloud-firestore-error-504-deadline-exceeded

Comment: Hey, as stated here[1], "'DEADLINE_EXCEEDED' - The deadline expired before the operation could complete" 

If you believe this need to be investigae more, I would recommend to provide details here for further investigation [2].


[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/status-codes#returned_codes
[2] https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187206&template=1162739